# if x bigger than y then return x smaller than y javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'am trying to make a simple calculation generator in prompt window. But it should not generate a negative number as answer, such as: x-y=-answer

My code so far:
[CodepenLink](https://codepen.io/o0309/pen/xmyoWz?editors=1010)
    [How it should look like](https://codepen.io/o0309/pen/xmyoWz?editors=1010)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var nxtRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var question = prompt("What is:"+ randomNumber+ " minus " + nxtRandomNumber);
  if(nxtRandomNumber > randomNumber){
    return ;
  }
  
  var result = Number(randomNumber) - Number(nxtRandomNumber);
 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Number:" + answer + " was right!";
 
}
```

```html
<p>Push the button to start </p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `question` is not used, and `answer` is undefined. I think you made a typo when writing `question`(it should be `answer`)

Comment: Are you looking for `Math.abs(-3) // 3` ?

Comment: "How it should look like": [link](https://i.postimg.cc/rmmnXBTG/123455555.png)

Answer (score 1):

make sure when you calculate `nxtRandomNumber` to use the value of `randomNumber` as a minimum.

So if `randomNumber` is 5, `nextRandomNumber` should be calculated to compute a number at least equal to 'randomNumber'

for ex:

```
nextRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + randomNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a trick to generate random number between 2 values.
`var nxtRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - randomNumber) + randomNumber);`

From mdn
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

> > > This example returns a random number between the specified values. The returned value is no lower than (and may possibly equal) min, and is less than (and not equal) max.>>>

Comment: This will generate the second random number as `random number between 10 and the first number`. So substracting `first - second` will not result in negative number, as the second number is never less than the first. Thanks for your concern

Comment: Although the result `first - second` can be 0 sometimes